# how to detect shift-enter in Elm?

Tags: elm

I've adapted the `onenter`code from the [todomvc example](https://github.com/evancz/elm-todomvc/blob/master/Todo.elm) to create `onShiftEnter`, but it does not work. Apparently, `shiftKey` is not passed to Elm.  So, how can I detect shift-Enter ?

```
onShiftEnter : Msg -> Attribute Msg
onShiftEnter msg =
  let
    tagger (code, shift) =
      if code == 13 && shift then msg else NoOp
  in
    on "keydown" 
       (Json.Decode.map tagger 
          ( Json.Decode.tuple2 (,)
              (Json.Decode.at ["keyCode"] Json.Decode.int)
              (Json.Decode.at ["shiftKey"] Json.Decode.bool)
          )
       )
```

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I've now edited the question to use shiftkey : still not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `Json.Decoder.object2` instead.
`Json.Decoder.tuple2` is used for decoding arrays.

```elm
import Json.Decode as Json exposing ((:=))

onShiftEnter : Msg -> Attribute Msg
onShiftEnter msg =
  let
    tagger (code, shift) =
      if code == 13 && shift then msg else NoOp
    keyExtractor =
      Json.object2 (,)
        ("keyCode" := Json.int)
        ("shiftKey" := Json.bool)
  in
    on "keydown" <| Json.map tagger keyExtractor
```

Answer (score 2):

Judging by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown, you need, 'Key', not 'Code', i.e.

```
(Json.Decode.at ["shiftKey"] Json.Decode.bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

Elm has changed since @Tosh's answer. Neither `tuple2` nor `object2` exist as standard decoding functions. Neither `:=` nor `(,)` is available. It would now look more like:

```
import Json.Decode as Json

onShiftEnter : Msg -> Attribute Msg
onShiftEnter msg =
    let
        tagger ( code, shift ) =
            if code == 13 && shift then
                msg

            else
                NoOp

        keyExtractor =
            Json.map2 Tuple.pair
                (Json.field "keyCode" Json.int)
                (Json.field "shiftKey" Json.bool)
    in
    on "keydown" <| Json.map tagger keyExtractor
```

Though I personally prefer `import Json.Decode as Decode` as a convention.

I would edit Tosh's answer but it is accurate at the time of writing and matches the style & version of the code in the question.